# Exact match Query in Elastic Search issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a `index` in `ElasticSearch` with 4 datas

Here's the Data:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sample4",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "UQBMOHABHstawU4w4_z3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2020-02-12T07:28:48",
          "target": {
            "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/2020/01/13/hello-world/": {
              "clicks": {
                "868 278": 12
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample4",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "UgBNOHABHstawU4wT_wn",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2020-02-12T07:29:15",
          "target": {
            "http://localhost/wordpress/": {
              "clicks": {
                "958 250": 5
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample4",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "UABMOHABHstawU4wC_y9",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2020-02-12T07:27:52",
          "target": {
            "http://localhost/wordpress/": {
              "clicks": {
                "880 257": 6
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample4",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "UwBOOHABHstawU4wFvxV",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2020-02-12T07:30:06",
          "target": {
            "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/2020/01/13/hello-world/": {
              "clicks": {
                "389 60": 33
              }
            },
            "http://localhost/wordpress/": {
              "clicks": {
                "657 235": 8
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to match the `target` key in the index with the value `http://localhost/wordpress/`. If the given value exactly matches the value in `target` key in ES index, I would get 3 data. Inside the target key, it was like an object. So i don't know how make a match query.

Here's the query i tried:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "target.http://localhost/wordpress/": {
                "value": "*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns 0 results.
Output I got:

```
  {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": {
          "value": 0,
          "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
      }
    }
```

Required Output:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sample4",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "UgBNOHABHstawU4wT_wn",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2020-02-12T07:29:15",
          "target": {
            "http://localhost/wordpress/": {
              "clicks": {
                "958 250": 5
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample4",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "UABMOHABHstawU4wC_y9",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2020-02-12T07:27:52",
          "target": {
            "http://localhost/wordpress/": {
              "clicks": {
                "880 257": 6
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample4",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "UwBOOHABHstawU4wFvxV",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2020-02-12T07:30:06",
          "target": {
            "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/2020/01/13/hello-world/": {
              "clicks": {
                "389 60": 33
              }
            },
            "http://localhost/wordpress/": {
              "clicks": {
                "657 235": 8
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Help me to solve this problem.....

Comment: @Lupanoide, I have posted my output in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're checking on a field name and not a value, you should try this query instead

```
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "target.http://localhost/wordpress/"
        }
    }
}
```